# How to understand which architecture apk should support?

Tags: android, gradle, native

My app uses the native code (my_native_lib.so), so when I build an apk it includes the copy of native lib for each architecture.

For example, my .so lib has a size of 10Mb and if I have 4 possible architectures "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" it means that .so file will be compiled for each one and finally the apk size will add +40Mb.

I'll describe my question more specific I use `opencv` in my project

[image]

as you can see opencv.so weight is ~63Mb and it coped for each architecture. Then I added `abiFilters` to my gradle file

```
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
```

I am excluded `opencv` from `mips` and `mips64` arc. *(Actually which devices are using this architecture?)*. But the question is still maybe I can exclude more architectures? But how to know which is possible to exclude and which is not?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there were any consumer devices using MIPS. In any case [MIPS ABI was removed in NDK r17](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis). Also `libopencv_java3.so` is only for `x86_64` architecture. It is unclear from your image what the size of the library is on other architectures.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I added an extended screenshot. I excluded MIPS because of the reason as you said (I also believe there should any consumers). I am not sure that opencv only for `x86_64`. Anyway according to the screenshot I see that each next architecture has a less size of opencv, I believe it is because it includes only those files that compatible with the architecture, no?

Comment: Correct. Best is always to test. `x86` and `x86_64` are really for emulator & ChromeOS devices: https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/device-support Also note that [App Bundle is becoming a requirement in the future](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html)  so at least in Play Store only architecture supported code will be sent to user device.